# Writing a vector as a linear combination of vectors from another basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

I have the bases $B=\{\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
2
\end{pmatrix}\}$ and $C=\{\begin{pmatrix}
-4 \\
2
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
5
\end{pmatrix}\}$.

I'm asked to write the vector $3\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} - 2\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ as a linear combination of the vectors from the basis $C$.

I don't understand how this is even possible. Using just the two vectors from $C$ I can't seem to get the result $\begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$ as needed. Is there something I'm missing? I've already found $P_{B\leftarrow C}$ and $P_{C\leftarrow B}$ but I'm not sure my answers are correct, and I'm not sure if the change of base matrices are even relevant here to express this linear combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a system of linear equations. We see that we want to solve the system 
$x_1$(-4,2) + $x_2$(2,5) = (5,-1). I don't think there is any need to discuss similar matrices.